# Sending form after validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC so it would be hard for me to explain, sorry for that!

I have a form in which I like to validate before sending using post method. the form is located in the Index.cshtml file and posting to HomeController. 
My problem is when I sending the form It's not reaching the right index() method (the second one in the HomeController with the CallMeNow request).

Is it possible to solve this in this way?

This is what I have in the HomeController.cs file:

```
    // GET: /Home/
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }



    // Send CallMeNow Request.
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(string txtCallMeNow)
    {
        if (txtCallMeNow != null)
        {
            // .. doing something here.
        }
        ViewBag.EmailSent = "Thank you.";

        return View();
```

This is I have in the Index.cshtml file:

1. This should validate the form and send it:

   ```
   $('#callMeNow1').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();  
       var selectedCity = $('#txtCallMeNow').val();
       if (selectedCity == 'enter phone number...')
           alert('enter phone number!');                               
       else
           document.location = $(this).prop('action');
   });
   ```
2. Here is the form. it should be posted the the HomeController:

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "callMeNow1" }))
       {
           <input type="text" id="txtCallMeNow" name="txtCallMeNow" onfocus="if(this.value != '') {this.value = '';}"
               onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'enter phone number...';}" value=" enter phone number..." /><br />
           <input type="submit" class="call_me_now" value="" /> 

            @ViewBag.EmailSent;
       }
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move  `e.preventDefault();` inside if condition . as it will stop form submitting. I believe you want to stop form submitting in case of validation failure.

```
$('#callMeNow1').submit(function (e) {

    var selectedCity = $('#txtCallMeNow').val();
    if (selectedCity == 'enter phone number...'){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert('enter phone number!'); 
    }                             

});
```